# Batch copy rename and resize images

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-processing, xcopy, batch-rename

I have a folder of 1000s of images all with different names and need to create differnt size images using command line in windows from the orginal file.

```
Images¬
       HC001¬
             HC001.jpg
       HC002¬
             HC002.jpg
       HC003¬
             HC003.jpg
       HX001¬
             HX001.jpg
```

What im trying to do is have

```
Images¬
       HC001¬
             HC001.jpg
             HC001-1920x1080.jpg
             HC001-1024x768.jpg
       HC002¬
             HC002.jpg
             HC002-1920x1080.jpg
             HC002-1024x768.jpg
       HC003¬
             HC003.jpg
             HC003-1920x1080.jpg
             HC003-1024x768.jpg
       HX001¬
             HX001.jpg
             HX001-1920x1080.jpg
             HX001-1024x768.jpg
```

My thinking was first to copy the images try and copy the images in each folder and then rename them, with size.

Then run a seperate script to look for the size prefix and resize to that.

Is this the most efficient wany to do it or can this be done all at once using a batch script.

So far i have `for /d /r %%a in (*.) do echo "%%a"` which show the folder list but i am now having difficultly opening the folder to search for .jpg files.

Any help would be welcome as I am new to batch files.

Comment: Irfanview has a command line mode and this could be done using that and a batch script.

Comment: You can also use imagemagik

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [**`scale.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imageProcessing/scale.bat) (without need to install external binaries) :

```
for /d /r "c:\Images" %%i in (*) do (
  if exist "%%~fi\%%~ni.jpg" (
    call scale.bat -source "%%~fi\%%~ni.jpg" -target "%%~fi\%%~ni-1920x1080.jpg" -max-width 1920 -max-height 1080 -keep-ratio no -force yes
    call scale.bat -source "%%~fi\%%~ni.jpg" -target "%%~fi\%%~ni-1024x768.jpg" -max-width 1024 -max-height 768 -keep-ratio no -force yes
  )
)
```

Most probably you have installed powershell so you can check also [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Resize-Image-File-f6dd4a56)

Comment: The code fragment hasn't worked for me, but the linked scale.bat file from GitHub works like a charm!